# Using ng-if with comparison operator

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have created a component 'OddComponent':

```
export class OddComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() oddscore = 0;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And it's html is:

```
<div ng-if="oddscore %2 ==0 ">
<p>
  odd works! {{oddscore}}
</p>
</div>
```

I am passing 'oddscore' variable from app component:

```
<app-odd [oddscore]="gameScore">
</app-odd>
```

My motive is to use ng-if to only print odd values in the component. But it seems that ng-if does not work as expected, as it prints all the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with the comparision, You are using angularjs syntax with angular, it should be **`*ngIf`**

```
<div *ngIf="oddscore%2 ==0 ">
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzegus?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: It worked. Thank you for correcting my silly mistake :)

Comment: Some are downvoting for no reason, mark if that helped